# Mutation probability for simple and complex problems

Tags: genetic-algorithms

Is It always better increase the mutation probability if the problem is more complex?

I'm doing different experiments trying to check if a higher mutation probability helps to find a solution when the problem is more complex. In this case i have a sphere función with 5 dimensions as "simple problem" and a Schwefel función with 10 dimensions as "complex problem". I'm trying to solve both problems using a genetic algorithm. Each variable is representes by 5 bits encoding real values in the [-10,10] range in the sphere function and 10 bits encoding values in the range [-500,500] for the Schwefel function.
The point is that trying different mutation probabilities  I get the best result for mutation probability between 0.01 and 0.03 for both problems. Increase the mutation probability make both problems work worst. Is this counter intuitive? Should I get better results for the complex problem for higher mutation probabilities?